# Importing data sets from plain-text files and performing operations on them

Tags: import, data

I am working with a lot of daily weather files in the `txt` format. I need to calculate a daily quantity from each of them, e.g., daily light intensity, which involves a simple summation of the light intensity column in Excel. As I am working with over three years of data, it is not possible to do this manually.

How can I automate this in *Mathematica*? Currently I import all the files using the following method. (Example shown is for Jan 1 to Jan 31)

```
filenames = FileNames[];  
TestList = Flatten[Table[Files[[j, i]], {j, 1, 31}, {i, 2, 1437}], 1];  
LightIntensity = TestList[[1 ;;, 5]];  
DailyLightIntensity = Partition[LightIntensity, 1436];  
DailySummation = Table[Total[DailyLightIntensity[[i]]],  {i, 1, 31}]
```

The method above only works assuming all the `txt` files contain rows from 2 to 1436, so I can use `Partition`, but I also need to handle cases with missing data.

I want to automate this process with *Mathematica* , import each `txt` file separately, perform the necessary calculations, and store the answer. How can this be done?

The naming convention of the txt is given below:

> [112] 2012-01-01
>   [112] 2012-01-02
>   [112] 2012-01-03
>   [112] 2012-01-04
>   ...
>   [112] 2012-12-31

Comment: Please see [editing help](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help).  Thanks.

Comment: Could you post a sample data file with and without missing data? What are you using `Paritition` for?

Comment: I am using the partition function to separate the long list of values into separate days. Eg: When I Import all the values for the light intensity I get a long list of values for 31 days. Therefore I will partition it into 31 parts to see the values for each day.

Comment: Partition is not the better way to do that. How to you import your txt? Do you have a sample txt?

Comment: @Murta The file can be found at [link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10371498/SampleFile.txt)

Comment: @Murta Thank you! Your method works well. I want to take it a step further and filter out all the values for light intensity below 50 and then carry out the summation. How would this be possible?

Comment: Hi @RaghavMalhotra. See if this edited version helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be a starting point:

```
data=Rest@Import["http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10371498/SampleFile.txt", "TSV"];
{First@StringSplit[data[[1, 1]]],Total[data[[All,2]]]}
```

So you get:

```
{"1/1/12", 308439.}
```

For many files and for filter data you can create a function like:

```
resumeFile[fileName_]:=Module[{data},
    data=Rest@Import[fileName, "TSV"];
    data=Select[data, #[[2]] > 50 &];
    {First@StringSplit[data[[1, 1]]],Total[data[[All,2]]]}
]
```

And make it operate in each txt like:

```
SetDirectory@"C:/txtPath"
files=FileNames["[112]*.txt"]
resumeFile/@files
```

You should get a list:

```
{{"1/2/12", 308439.},{"1/2/12", 208389.}, ... , {"1/3/12", 508439.}}
```

Comment: Thank you for choosing my answer. I hope it helped. :)