# Importing a text file into a matrix format

Tags: import, data, random

I am attempting to perform a comparison of pseudorandom number generation with the RAND Corporation's "A Million Random Digits with 100,000 Normal Deviates" for a Computational Physics course.

I have the text file, which is available from the [RAND Website](http://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/monograph_reports/MR1418/MR1418.digits.txt.zip).  I have tried Import and Import["data.txt", Table] with minimal success.  My desire is to get this in a table format where I can then use them in a Monte Carlo simulation.  I would prefer to be able to address this in the format "randData[m,n]" like addressing the value in an m,n matrix.

I am aware of similar questions, and have used the search. Thanks in advance for your assistance.

[importing a matrix](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20780/importing-a-matrix-from-a-text-file) 
[Importing data sets from plain-text files and performing operations on them](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19624/importing-data-sets-from-plain-text-files-and-performing-operations-on-them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import = Import["c:\\users\\rasher\\downloads\\digits.txt"];
randData = Partition[ToExpression[StringSplit[import]], 11];

randData[[1, 10]]

( * 39292 *)
```

randData is `[[line, column]]` of the text, in numeric form.